# Why does solving this integral using trigonometric substitution lead to the wrong answer?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I was solving the integral $$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 16}}{x} \, dx,$$ and I admittedly attempted to solve it blindly using trigonometric substitution:

$$\begin{align}
&\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 16}}{x} \, dx, \quad \text{let } x = 4\sec\theta \implies dx = 4\sec\theta\tan\theta \, d\theta \quad(\text{meaning} \ \ \theta=\sec^{-1}\frac{x}{4})\\[0.5em]
&\int \frac{\sqrt{16\sec^2\theta - 16}}{4\sec\theta} \cdot 4\sec\theta\tan\theta = \int 4\tan^2\theta \, d\theta = \int 4(\sec^2\theta - 1) \, d\theta = 4\tan\theta - 4\theta + c \\[0.5em]
&4\tan\theta - 4\theta + c \ \ \text{becomes} \ \ \sqrt{x^2-16} - 4\sec^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{x}{4}\Bigr) + c \ \ \text{so} \ \ \fbox{$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 16}}{x} \, dx = \sqrt{x^2-16} - 4\sec^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{x}{4}\Bigr) + c$}
\end{align}$$

So $\sqrt{x^2-16} - 4\sec^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{x}{4}\Bigr) + c$ is the family of antiderivates of $\frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 16}}{x}$, so if $$F(x) = \sqrt{x^2-16} - 4\sec^{-1}\Bigl(\frac{x}{4}\Bigr),$$ then $$F'(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 16}}{x}$$, right? However, as the graph below shows, that's not the case.

[image: [![Graph][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSjO6.png]

For negative values, the two functions $F'$ and $f$ do not match at all. When setting
$$F(x) = \sqrt{x^2 - 16} - 4\tan^{-1}\biggl(\frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 16}}{4}\biggr),$$ then the two functions do seem to agree.

When I tried to ask an instructor, I was told that we always represent our solutions in terms of either inverse tangent or inverse sine, but not inverse secant. The reason I confidently chose to represent theta as inverse secant is that that's how we always did it, so when I compared my answers to the ones provided, I was extremely confused.

I fear that it might be an issue with the domain of the inverse secant, but I'm not exactly sure how.

Comment: I think this has to do with $\sec^{-1}$ being typically defined as having a range of $[0,\pi/2)\cup(\pi/2,\pi]$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this might be the cause of the issue?

Comment: cleaner to take $x = 4 \cosh t $     There is then a Weierstrass substitution that takes that to  a rational function... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#Hyperbolic_functions

Comment: If you were integrating this over negative $x$, you would need to choose $\theta$ bounds in $(\pi/2,\pi]$ for $\theta=\sec^{-1}(x/4)$ to be correct, given this choice of definition for $\sec^{-1}$. But then in the second line $\sqrt{16\sec^2(\theta)-16}$ should be $-4\tan(\theta)$, not $4\tan(\theta)$, because $\theta$ is in $(\pi/2,\pi]$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, recall that $\sqrt{y^2} = \lvert y\rvert,$ not $y$, because $\sqrt{y^2}$ is a non-negative square root even when $y$ is negative.
Also note that $0 \leq \sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right) < \dfrac\pi2$ if and only if $x \geq 4,$
but $\dfrac\pi2 < \sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right) \leq \pi$ if and only if $x \leq -4.$
Then

\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sqrt{16\sec^2\theta - 16}}{4\sec\theta}\,
     &\cdot 4\sec\theta\tan\theta \,\mathrm d\theta \\
&= \int \sqrt{16\tan^2\theta}\,\tan\theta \,\mathrm d\theta \\
&= 4 \int \lvert\tan\theta\rvert \tan\theta \,\mathrm d\theta \\
&= \begin{cases}
\phantom{-}4 \displaystyle\int\tan^2\theta \,\mathrm d\theta  & 0 \leq \theta < \dfrac\pi2,\\
-4 \displaystyle\int\tan^2\theta \,\mathrm d\theta &\dfrac\pi2 < \theta \leq \pi \\
\end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases}
4 \left( \tan\theta - \theta\right) + C_1 & 0 \leq \theta < \dfrac\pi2,\\
4 \left(\theta - \tan\theta\right) + C_2 & \dfrac\pi2 < \theta \leq \pi \\
\end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases}
4 \left(\tan \left(\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right)\right)
 - \sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right)\right) + C_1 & x \geq 4,\\
4 \left(\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right)
  - \tan \left(\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right)\right)\right) + C_2 & x \leq -4. \\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Now when $x \geq 4,$ then
$\tan \left(\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right)\right) = \dfrac14 \sqrt{x^2 - 16},$
sure enough, but when $x \leq -4$ then
$\dfrac\pi2 < \sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right) \leq \pi$ (second quadrant),
hence $\tan \left(\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right)\right)$ is negative (or zero),
hence $\tan \left(\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right)\right) = -\dfrac14 \sqrt{x^2 - 16}.$
So

$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 16}}{x} \, dx
= \begin{cases}
\sqrt{x^2 - 16} - 4\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right) + C_1 & x \geq 4,\\
\sqrt{x^2 - 16} + 4 \sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right) + C_2 & x \leq -4. \\
\end{cases}
$$

Further notice that when $x \geq 4,$ then
$\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right) = \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}4\right),$
but when $x \leq -4,$ then
$\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right) = \pi - \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}4\right),$
so the integral can also be written

\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 16}}{x} \, dx
&= \begin{cases}
\sqrt{x^2 - 16} - 4 \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}4\right) + C_1
 & x \geq 4,\\
\sqrt{x^2 - 16} + 4\left(\pi - \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}4\right)\right) + C_2
 & x \leq -4 \\
\end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases}
\sqrt{x^2 - 16} - 4 \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}4\right) + C_1 & x \geq 4,\\
\sqrt{x^2 - 16} - 4 \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}4\right) + C_3 & x \leq -4. \\
\end{cases} \\
\end{align}

If we set $C_1 = C_3 = C$ then we have the solution you might get by other means,
$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 16}}{x} \, dx
= \sqrt{x^2 - 16} - 4 \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}4\right) + C,
$$
but in the context of real analysis it is more accurate to say that we can use different constants in the integral for each connected part of the integral's domain.

---

Some parts of the calculations that were postponed for the sake of the flow of the answer:

Why is $\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right) = \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}4\right)$ when $x \geq 4$?

Let $x \geq 4$ and $\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right) = \theta.$
Then $\sec\theta = \dfrac x4$ and $\theta$ is in the first quadrant (since $\dfrac x4 > 0$), so

$$
\tan^2\theta = \sec^2\theta - 1 = \dfrac{x^2}{16} - 1 = \dfrac{x^2-16}{16},
$$

so $\tan\theta = \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{x^2-16}{16}}.$
But since $\theta$ is in the first quadrant,
$\tan\theta$ must be positive, so $\tan\theta = \sqrt{\dfrac{x^2-16}{16}}$
and (again, since $\theta$ is in the first quadrant)
$$\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right) = \theta
 = \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}4\right).$$

Why is $\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right)
= \pi - \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}4\right)$ when $x \leq -4$?

Note that when $y \leq -1,$ then $\sec^{-1} y = \pi - \sec^{-1}(-y).$
This comes from the way we define the inverse secant function;
like the inverse cosine function, we use the second quadrant for negative values.
And if $y \leq -1$ then $-y \geq 1,$ so $\sec^{-1}(-y)$ is a first-quadrant angle, so $\pi - \sec^{-1}(-y)$ is a second-quadrant angle and

$$
\sec\left(\pi - \sec^{-1}(-y)\right) = -\sec\left(\sec^{-1}(-y)\right)
= -(-y) = y,
$$

as required. Now let $x \leq -4$; then $-x \geq 4$ and (substituting $-x$ for $x$ in the what we worked out above for $x \geq 4$)
$$
\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac {(-x)}4\right)
 = \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{(-x)^2-16}}4\right)
 = \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}4\right),
$$
and
$$
\sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac x4\right)
 = \pi - \sec^{-1}\left(\dfrac {(-x)}4\right)
 = \pi - \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}4\right).
$$

Comment: Ah, I finally can rest. This problem has been haunting me for a couple of months! One thing though. When you say, "when $x \le −4$ then $\frac{π}{2}< \sec^{−1}(\frac{x}{4}) \le \pi$, hence $\tan(\sec^{−1}(\frac{x}{4}))$ is **non-negative**, hence $\tan(\sec^{−1}(\frac{x}{4}))=−\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{x^2−16}$", wouldn't $\tan(\sec^{−1}(\frac{x}{4}))$ actually be negative on that interval? Also, how do you reach the conclusion that for $x \le -4$ $$\sec^{-1}(\frac{x}{4})=\pi-\tan^{-1}\biggl(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}{4}$$? Is there an identity? Similarly, how do you determine the relationship for $x \ge 4$?

Comment: **EDIT** (because apparently, I can't edit the original comment): When you say, "when $x\le−4$ then $\frac{π}{2}<\sec^{−1}(\frac{x}{4})\le\pi$, hence $\tan(\sec^{−1}(\frac{x}{4}))$ is **non-negative**, hence $\tan(\sec^{−1}(\frac{x}{4}))=−\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{x^2−16}$", wouldn't $\tan(\sec^{−1}(\frac{x}{4}))$ actually be negative on that interval? Also, how do you reach the conclusion that for $x\le-4$ $$\sec^{-1}\biggl(\frac{x}{4}\biggr)=\pi-\tan^{-1}\biggl(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}{4}\biggr)$$? Is there an identity? Similarly, how do you determine the relationship for $x\ge4$?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}{x} d x=&\int \frac{x^2-16}{x \sqrt{x^2-16}} d x \\
= & \int \frac{x^2-16}{x^2} d\left(\sqrt{x^2-16}\right) \\
= & \int\left(1-\frac{16}{x^2}\right) d\left(\sqrt{x^2-16}\right) \\
= & \sqrt{x^2-16}-16 \int \frac{d\left(\sqrt{x^2-16}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x^2-16}\right)^2+4^2} \\
= & \sqrt{x^2-16}-4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-16}}{4}\right)+C \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: You are right. Thank you.

Comment: I sense that there is a u-sub somewhere over here. I apologize if it is quite clear, but I've never seen a differential like that before (not in the course, at least). What does $d(\sqrt{x^2 - 16})$ mean? How does it work?

Comment: You may treat $u=\sqrt{x^2-16}$ if it makes you uncomfortable.

Comment: It was rather intriguing! Is there a name for this technique? How does it work?